# validate data with annotations for internal method using spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I am a spring newbie so please bear with me. But I wanted to know if annotations based validation can be used to non form methods as well ? I know that `BindingResult` can be used for input form validation. But I have something like this :

```
public class Service{
  @NotBlank
  @Column
  private String name;
}


public class ServiceController{
    @PostMapping
    public Service create() {
        ... some additional code...
        return createServiceObject();
    }

    private Service createServiceObject(){
        ...some additional code...
        Service s = new Service();
        /* I want Not Blank validation for name to get triggered here */
        s.setName(someInputFromForm)
    }
}
```

And I want name to get validated based on annotation @NotBlank as opposed to me checking it manually like : `name.trim.isEmpty()`. Is this possible ?

Comment: Please refer to some tutorials about form validation.

Comment: I am trying to do non-form validation, in private internal method. That's why the question.

Comment: And there are many tutorials about creating a custom, you can validate by field using your own annotation, you can validate an object as a whole, so for instance if you had int a, b; you could check that a + b < 10, etc. Validation is relevant in 2 areas in Spring, serialization and submitting forms.

Comment: You use groups to tell Spring when a field should be valid

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out on this you just need to have a bit of a look, google form validation, serialization validation, custom hibernate annotation validation etc. You will find your answers there, IMHO I don't think it is good to ask these sorts of questions on SO it's just that if too many novices ask these questions then the site will be clogged up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new bean of `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` class into configuration, if you not added yet. If you're using java config then something like:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean(){
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

}
```

Or if you're using xml config, then:

```
<beans>
   ...
   <bean id="validatorFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
   </bean>
</beans>
```

If you already have added `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` bean into your configuration, just set the name of this bean (you'll need it for dependency injection).

Now you can use this bean as validator:

```
public class ServiceController{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("validatorFactoryBean")
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean;

    @PostMapping
    public Service create() {
        ... some additional code...
        return createServiceObject();
    }

    private Service createServiceObject(){
        Service service = new Service();
        service.setName(someInputFromForm)

        DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(service);
        binder.addValidators(validatorFactoryBean);
        binder.validate();
        BindingResult result = binder.getBindingResult();
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            // here you can throw exception or do something else
        }
        return service;
    }
}
```